# webdriver how to focus on file upload window when the window Minimized or Maximize the window

Tags: file-upload, selenium, webdriver

everyone,i have a problem about file upload.

i use pc A to remote logining pc B;

PS:pc B has eclipse and webdriver code ;

i  maximize the remoting window(PC B), the file upload window can focus on. when i

minimize or close the remoting window(pc b) ,the file upload wind can't foucs on.

here is my code.

```
CommonAction.findElement(driver, "SWFUpload_0", "id").click();
setClipboardData(fileUrl);
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.delay(1000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.delay(1000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

use

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
```

don't work,can't focus on the file upload window.

Selenium version:2.27
OS:wind 7
Browser:chrome
Browser version:26

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

- You can't handle windows event through selenium.
- This is main disadvantage of selenium.
- you can use to "sikuli + selenium" means have to use SIKULI's API to handle this event.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you.
Javascript alert makes your browser focus on window. Just add this code.
And you are good to go!

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("alert('Focus window')");
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```